# Remove whitespace before a specific character in python?

Tags: python, string, ocr, whitespace, strip

I was wondering if you knew the best way to do this.

This program uses OCR to read text. Occasionally, spaces appear before a decimal point like so:

```
{'MORTON BASSET BLK SESAME SEE': '$6.89'}
{"KELLOGG'S RICE KRISPIES": '$3.49'}
{'RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK': '$1 .49'}
```

as you can see, a space appears before the decimal point on the last entry. Any ideas on how to strip JUST this whitespace?

Thank you :)

EDIT: contents before decimal point may contain a varying amount of whitespace. Like

```
$1    .49
$1  .49
$1 .49
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

```
import re
a_list = {"1 .49", "1   .49", "1          .49"}

for a in a_list:
  print re.sub(' +.', '.', a)
```

Result will be

```
1.49
1.49
1.49
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just strip out all whitespace from the string, assuming that they follow the same format.  SOmething like this:

```
for item in items: 
  for key in item.keys():
    item[key] = item[key].replace(" ", "")
```

The key part is replacing the whitespace with no whitespace.

If you *just* want the whitespace before the ".", then you could use:
.replace(" .", ".") instead.

This would only replace 1 white space.  To replace multiple, you could use a while loop like this:

```
while ' .' in item[key]:
  item[key].replace(' .', '.')
```

Comment: I added the edot by looking at the OP's comment on a different answer.  props to @ncfirth for the quick response.  Note, though, that that answer would also replace the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

For your dict obj:-

```
>>> d = {'RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK': '$1 .49'}
>>> d['RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK'] = d['RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK'].replace(' ','')
>>> d
{'RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK': '$1.49'}
```

Even if there is varying space; replace would work fine. See this:-

```
>>> d = {'RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK': '$1       .49'}
>>> d['RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK'] = d['RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK'].replace(' ','')
>>> d
{'RAID FLY RIBBON 4PK': '$1.49'}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that maybe you want something more generic not only for that key:

```
for key, value in d.items():
   d[key]=value.replace(" ","")
```

in this way independent of the key othe number of space the result will be without white spaces

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with split and join:

```
"".join("1     .49".split())
```

This works because splits on one or more spaces. To do this for each value in a dictionary:

```
{k, "".join(v.split()) for k,v in dict_.items()}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sure:

```
string.replace(' .', '')
```

Comment: thank you :) would this work if the string had more than one whitespace?

Comment: @NicholasNowak It won't.

Comment: No. I'd look at the answer using regex for that.